# Where would the Limit statement go? Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sql-limit

Short Question, where would the limit clause go in Postgresql?
I want to limit the amount of rows to 10, but it is giving me an error when I do;

```
From this_table x
    join this_table y
    on x.no = y.no


where x.no = '7'
Limit 10
group by x.location
order by x.location
```

It's giving me a syntax error at or near "where"

(If requested, I could add the select statement.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limit` is the last clause in a `select` query, so it goes after the `order by`:

```
select <whatever>
From this_table x
    join this_table y
    on x.no = y.no
where x.no = '7'
group by x.location
order by x.location
Limit 10;
```